# Unable to locate persister : org.ceri.gestiondonnees.entities.Utilisateur

Tags: java, spring, hibernate

I'm getting the error below but I don't know what is the problem. My entity is correctly written and the associated table exist also on database.

This is my entity

```java
package org.ceri.gestiondonnees.entities;

import java.io.Serializable;

import javax.persistence.Entity;
import javax.persistence.GeneratedValue;
import javax.persistence.GenerationType;
import javax.persistence.Id;

@Entity
public class Utilisateur implements Serializable{

    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy=GenerationType.IDENTITY)
    private int id ; 
    private String email ; 
    private String nom ;
    private String prenom ; 
    private String password ;

    public Utilisateur() {
        super();
        // TODO Auto-generated constructor stub
    }

    public Utilisateur(String nom, String prenom, String email, String password) 
    {
        super();
        this.nom = nom;
        this.prenom = prenom;
        this.email = email;
        this.password = password;
    }

    public String getNom() {
        return nom;
    }

    public void setNom(String nom) {
        this.nom = nom;
    }

    public String getPrenom() {
        return prenom;
    }

    public void setPrenom(String prenom) {
        this.prenom = prenom;
    }

    public String getEmail() {
        return email;
    }
```

Here is a the method of my spring's controller where I'm invoking the business layer

```
@RequestMapping(value = "/signin")
public String logIn(UserForm userForm, Model model) {
    Utilisateur user = metier.getUser(1) ;
    return "home";
}
```

The business method

```
@Override
public Utilisateur getUser(int idUser) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    Utilisateur  user =  em.find(Utilisateur.class, idUser);
    return user;
}
```

This is the exception that I got

```
Caused by: java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Unable to locate persister: org.ceri.gestiondonnees.entities.Utilisateur
at org.hibernate.jpa.spi.AbstractEntityManagerImpl.find(AbstractEntityManagerImpl.java:1097)
at org.hibernate.jpa.spi.AbstractEntityManagerImpl.find(AbstractEntityManagerImpl.java:1033)
at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source)
at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source)
at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Unknown Source)
at org.springframework.orm.jpa.SharedEntityManagerCreator$SharedEntityManagerInvocationHandler.invoke(SharedEntityManagerCreator.java:240)
at com.sun.proxy.$Proxy36.find(Unknown Source)
at org.ceri.gestiondonnees.dao.UsersDaoImpl.getUser(UsersDaoImpl.java:38)
at org.ceri.gestiondonnees.metier.UserMetierImpl.getUser(UserMetierImpl.java:31)
at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source)
at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source)
at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Unknown Source)
at org.springframework.aop.support.AopUtils.invokeJoinpointUsingReflection(AopUtils.java:318)
at org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.invokeJoinpoint(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:183)
at org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.proceed(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:150)
at org.springframework.transaction.interceptor.TransactionInterceptor$1.proceedWithInvocation(TransactionInterceptor.java:96)
at org.springframework.transaction.interceptor.TransactionAspectSupport.invokeWithinTransaction(TransactionAspectSupport.java:260)
at org.springframework.transaction.interceptor.TransactionInterceptor.invoke(TransactionInterceptor.java:94)
at org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.proceed(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:172)
at org.springframework.aop.framework.JdkDynamicAopProxy.invoke(JdkDynamicAopProxy.java:202)
at com.sun.proxy.$Proxy38.getUser(Unknown Source)
at org.ceri.gestiondonnees.controllers.UserController.logIn(UserController.java:52)
at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source)
at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source)
at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Unknown Source)
at org.springframework.web.method.support.InvocableHandlerMethod.invoke(InvocableHandlerMethod.java:213)
at org.springframework.web.method.support.InvocableHandlerMethod.invokeForRequest(InvocableHandlerMethod.java:126)
at org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.annotation.ServletInvocableHandlerMethod.invokeAndHandle(ServletInvocableHandlerMethod.java:96)
at org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.annotation.RequestMappingHandlerAdapter.invokeHandlerMethod(RequestMappingHandlerAdapter.java:617)
at org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.annotation.RequestMappingHandlerAdapter.handleInternal(RequestMappingHandlerAdapter.java:578)
at org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.AbstractHandlerMethodAdapter.handle(AbstractHandlerMethodAdapter.java:80)
at org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet.doDispatch(DispatcherServlet.java:923)
at org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet.doService(DispatcherServlet.java:852)
at org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.processRequest(FrameworkServlet.java:882)
... 42 more
Caused by: org.hibernate.UnknownEntityTypeException: Unable to locate persister: org.ceri.gestiondonnees.entities.Utilisateur
at org.hibernate.internal.SessionFactoryImpl.locateEntityPersister(SessionFactoryImpl.java:824)
at org.hibernate.internal.SessionImpl.locateEntityPersister(SessionImpl.java:2906)
at org.hibernate.internal.SessionImpl.access$2500(SessionImpl.java:167)
at org.hibernate.internal.SessionImpl$IdentifierLoadAccessImpl.<init>(SessionImpl.java:2662)
at org.hibernate.internal.SessionImpl$IdentifierLoadAccessImpl.<init>(SessionImpl.java:2648)
at org.hibernate.internal.SessionImpl.byId(SessionImpl.java:1105)
at org.hibernate.internal.SessionImpl.get(SessionImpl.java:978)
at org.hibernate.jpa.spi.AbstractEntityManagerImpl.find(AbstractEntityManagerImpl.java:1075)
 ... 78 more
```

**Spring Bean XML**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<beans xmlns="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans"
       xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
       xmlns:context="http://www.springframework.org/schema/context"
       xmlns:tx="http://www.springframework.org/schema/tx"
       xsi:schemaLocation="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans 
          http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans/spring-beans.xsd
           http://www.springframework.org/schema/context 
          http://www.springframework.org/schema/context/spring-context-3.1.xsd
          http://www.springframework.org/schema/tx 
          http://www.springframework.org/schema/tx/spring-tx-4.3.xsd"> 

<bean id="dao"  class="org.ceri.gestiondonnees.dao.UsersDaoImpl"></bean>

<bean id="businessLogic" class="org.ceri.gestiondonnees.metier.UserMetierImpl"> 
    <property name="usersDao" ref="dao"></property>
</bean>

<!-- data source -->
<bean id="dataSource" class="org.springframework.jdbc.datasource.DriverManagerDataSource">
    <property name="driverClassName" value="com.mysql.jdbc.Driver"></property>
    <property name="url" value="jdbc:mysql://127.0.0.1/usersdb"></property>
    <property name="username" value="root"></property>
    <property name="password" value=""></property>
</bean>

<!-- persistenceUnit manager  -->
<bean id="persistenceUnitManager" class="org.springframework.orm.jpa.persistenceunit.DefaultPersistenceUnitManager">
    <property name="persistenceXmlLocations">
        <list>
            <value>classpath*:META-INF/persistence.xml</value>
        </list>
    </property>
    <property name="defaultDataSource" ref="dataSource"></property>
</bean>

<!-- entityManagerFactory  -->
<bean id="entityManagerFactory" class="org.springframework.orm.jpa.LocalContainerEntityManagerFactoryBean">
    <property name="persistenceUnitManager" ref="persistenceUnitManager"></property>
    <property name="persistenceUnitName" value="usersDataBase"></property>  
</bean>

<!-- transactionManager -->
<bean id="transactionManager" class="org.springframework.orm.jpa.JpaTransactionManager">
    <property name="entityManagerFactory" ref="entityManagerFactory"></property>
</bean>
<tx:annotation-driven transaction-manager="transactionManager"/>
<context:annotation-config></context:annotation-config>
</beans>
```

**Hibernate Configuration**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
 <persistence xmlns="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/persistence"
         xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
         xsi:schemaLocation="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/persistence http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/persistence/persistence_2_0.xsd"
         version="2.0">
  <persistence-unit name="usersDataBase" transaction-type="RESOURCE_LOCAL">
    <provider>org.hibernate.jpa.HibernatePersistenceProvider</provider>
    <properties>
      <property name="hibernate.show_sql" value="true"/>
      <property name="hibernate.hbm2ddl.auto" value="create"/>
    </properties>
 </persistence-unit>
<persistence>
```

Comment: Please post your Hibernate configuration xml file (xxx.cfg.xml) and also spring bean xml. This type of exception occurs when you have bad configuration.

Comment: I understand everything except the "org.ceri.gestiondonnees.metier.UserMetierImpl". What is this class? Could you please show your JARs and project path too?

Comment: "org.ceri.gestiondonnees.metier.UserMetierImpl" is the business layer wich interact with DAO layer